# Load with the convenience of require

Tags: ruby

`require` loads a rubygem, but it cannot find/reload the file when it's new or changed (eg: if you issue a `gem install x` a new requireable/loadable file is installed, but `require` won't find it).

```
require 'json'
#=> true
require 'json'
#=> false
```

On the other hand, `load` can reload a file.

```
load 'path/to/json.rb'
#=> true
load 'path/to/json.rb'
#=> true
```

However, `load` requires the path to the ruby file, while `require` is flexible to find it in the default location.

Is there an intermediate function `f` that can return, given the rubygem name, the path of the file to be loaded? (It would, indeed, have been convenient that `require` return it instead of just `true`, but that wasn't the way it was coded.) So I could call it this way:

```
load f 'json'
```

Comment: `require` is not just for rubygems.

Comment: i  know.....,...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "`require` cannot load a file when its' new". That is not true.

Comment: The two methods `require` and `load` both return `true` or `false`. Not sure what you mean by "an intermediate function ... that returns the path of the file to be loaded". That has nothing to do with `require` vs. `load`.

Comment: I updated the question to address your doubts (although I didn't bring any new facts to it, I believe)

Answer (score 2):

`require` will try different extensions (e.g. .rb., .so, .dll, etc) to find the file you are requiring in the `$LOAD_PATH` when the path given is not an absolute path e.g.

```
require 'json' # this will try 'json.rb' first
```

`load` will also search the `$LOAD_PATH` when the path is not absolute but it will not try and add any extensions for you, instead you would have to be specific about it e.g.

```
load 'json.rb'
```

If you want to know where that file is loading from you could use the `Gem::Specification` class like so:

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name('json').full_gem_path
```

This will return the path to the directory of the file that would be `loaded` or `required`.

**DISCLAIMER**: The below is for edification purposes only and should not be used in production code of any kind

If you really wanted something like this this you could try:

```
module Kernel 
  def load_and_print_gem(gem_name, *requirements)
    begin 
      spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name(gem_name, *requirements)
      path = File.join(spec.full_gem_path, 'lib', "#{gem_name}.rb") 
      puts "Loading #{gem_name} from Gem::Specification: #{path}" if File.exist?(path)
      load path
    rescue Gem::MissingSpecError, LoadError => e 
      if path = $LOAD_PATH.find {|p| Dir.glob("#{p}/**/#{gem_name}.rb").any? }
        puts "Loading #{gem_name} from $LOAD_PATH: #{path}/#{gem_name}.rb" 
      end
      load File.join(path.to_s,"#{gem_name}.rb")
    end
  end
end
```

**NOTE: `$LOAD_PATH` fall back will load the first `.rb` file it finds matching the `gem_name` not necessarily the newest gem version or even the gem itself if there are more than 1 in `$LOAD_PATH` directories**

Then

```
load_and_print_gem('json') 
# Loading: /path/to/json.rb
#=> true
```

Or to try (will not work with $LOAD_PATH fallback) to load and print a specific version: (See [`Gem::Requirement`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Requirement.html) for more details on the requirements)

```
load_and_print_gem('json','= 2.0.3')
```

[Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/FortunateLeafyFactor)